# How can I combine two elasticsearch responses into one?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I currently stuck with a result response from a multi-search that returns an array of responses for each query I add, but I need the responses to be combined so that the relevancy can determine their order. Getting back two separated lists of hits isn't great for creating a unified search results page.

My current code for searching is:

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb1 = client.prepareSearch(index)                     
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString(query).field("body").field("title").field("author")
    .addHighlightedField("body").addHighlightedField("title").addHighlightedField("author")
    .setHighlighterPreTags("<div class='highlight'>").setHighlighterPostTags("</div>");

SearchRequestBuilder srb2 = client.prepareSearch(index2)                    
    .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(
        QueryBuilders.queryString(query)
        .field("file")
        .field("title")
        .field("author")
    )
    .addHighlightedField("file").addHighlightedField("title").addHighlightedField("author")
    .setHighlighterPreTags("<div class='highlight'>").setHighlighterPostTags("</div>");

MultiSearchResponse sr = client.prepareMultiSearch()
    .add(srb1)
    .add(srb2)
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Thanks for any help you all can give!

---

Edit:
This is my final code

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb = client
                            .prepareSearch(index,index2)    
                            .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                            .setQuery(
                                QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                                .should(
                                    QueryBuilders.queryString(query)
                                    .field("body")
                                    .field("title")
                                    .field("author")
                                )
                                .should(
                                    QueryBuilders.queryString(query)
                                    .field("file")
                                    .field("title")
                                    .field("author")
                                )
                                .minimumNumberShouldMatch(1)
                            )
                            .addHighlightedField("title")
                            .addHighlightedField("author")
                            .addHighlightedField("body")    
                            .addHighlightedField("file")
                            .setHighlighterPreTags("<div class='highlight'>")
                            .setHighlighterPostTags("</div>");                  
SearchResponse sr = srb.execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a MultiSearch I'd use a Bool Query:

> **Bool Query**
>
> A query that matches documents matching boolean combinations of other
>   queries. The bool query maps to Lucene BooleanQuery. It is built using
>   one or more boolean clauses, each clause with a typed occurrence. The
>   occurrence types are:
>
> **must**
>
> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents.
>
> **should**
>
> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. In a
>   boolean query with no must clauses, one or more should
>   clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to
>   match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.
>
> **must_not**
>
> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

In your case I'd combine your two queries using a should clause. Something like this:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders
                    .boolQuery()
                    .should(termQuery("yourfield", "query1"))
                    .should(termQuery("yourfield", "query2"));
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html

Comment: So how will tat work with the different highlighted fields? And the two different indexes?

Comment: I don't see anything about two different indexes in your question, but the java api supports searching more than one index at a time: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my code to make it more clear. I am confused how with two separate indexes (that also have differing structures) I can query and highlight?