# Search Multiple Indexes with condition

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is requirement I am working on

1. There are multiple indexes with name content_ssc, content_teal, content_mmy.
2. These indexes can have common data (co_code is one of the field in the documents of these indexes)

   a.       content_ssc can have documents with co_code = teal/ssc/mmy

   b.      content_mmy can have documents with co_code = ssc/mmy
3. I need to get the data using below condition (this is one of the approach to get the unique data from these indexes)

   a.       (Index = content_ssc and site_code = ssc) OR (Index = content_mmy and site_code = mmy)
4. Basically I am getting a duplicate data from these indexes currently so I need any solution which should fetch unique data from these indexes using the above condition.

I have tried using boolean query with multiple indices from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145385/how-can-i-combine-two-elasticsearch-responses-into-one) link but it didn't produce unique result.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [distinct](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html) query , and you will get unique result